# Style .txt file in a html body

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a blog script with php i have also created an admin area, in the admin area it has a text box with a submit button, what happens is i type some text into the text box and press the submit code then it generates a text file into a folder, in the main index file i have put come php code that displays all the text files into a div, but i want to style the text files i have tryed many ways to style the text files without editing the text files themselves, any ideas? i can change the text files to .html or .doc, [here is a link with the php files](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bOY80I-y50HUrk97Apbp71DFVv6uYSAWGythBLPDcEs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Use div tag with class attribute to style your .txt file

```
<?php
foreach (glob("posts/*.txt") as $file) {
$file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
echo "<div class='styleTxt'>";
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    echo $line;
}
echo "</div>";
fclose($file_handle);
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  foreach (glob("posts/*.txt") as $file) {
      $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
      $content="<div class='yourdesiredstyleclass'>";
      while (!feof($file_handle)) {
       $line = fgets($file_handle);
       $content.='<div class="your style class for line">'; 
       $content.= $line; 
       $content.="</div>";
      }
      $content.="</div>";
      echo  $content ;
      fclose($file_handle);
 }
?>
```

you can apply style to each word also by printing word with style also you can apply style to each character by printing character with style.